# How does the c# language prevent generics from being covarient unless they contain no methods that require T as an input?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, type-systems

I have been reading up on the changes that .NET4.5 will bring, and on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj133817.aspx) blog post I stumbled upon something I neither knew nor understood.

When talking about the implementation of readonly collections, [Immo Landwerth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee532098.aspx?sdmr=ImmoLandwerth&sdmi=authors) says:

> Unfortunately, our type system doesn’t allow making types of T covariant unless it has no methods that take T as an input. Therefore, we can’t add an IndexOf method to IReadOnlyList. We believe this is a small sacrifice compared to not having support for covariance.

From my obviously limited understanding, it seems like he is saying that in order to enable us to call a method that requires an `IReadOnlyList<Shape>` by passing in a `IReadOnlyList<Circle>`, we can't have a `IReadOnlyList<T>.IndexOf(T someShape)` method.

I don't see how the type system would prevent that. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose `Circle` implements `IEquatable<Circle>`. That would naturally be used by `IReadOnlyList<Circle>.IndexOf` if it were available. Now if you could write this:

```
IReadOnlyList<Circle> circles = ...;
IReadOnlyList<Shape> shapes = circles;
int index = shapes.IndexOf(new Square(10));
```

that would end up trying to pass a `Square` to `Circle.Equals(Circle)` which would clearly be a bad idea.

The rules which enforce the "no values of `T` in input positions" are in section 13.1.3 of the C# 4 spec. You should also read [Eric Lippert's blog series on generic variance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/) for a *lot* more details.

Comment: Fair enough. I would have thought IndexOf would just return -1 if it received an incorrect type. Dunno why I thought that, that would imply needing some kind of type checking in each method. I'll get right into eric's blog posts. Boy but that man can explain something in a way I can understand!

Comment: What a covariant `IReadOnlyList<T>` could implement would be `IndexOf<TT>(TT it)`, where the parameter type of the method was independent from that of the collection.  A class `List<TItem>` could implement its `IndexOf` could then use a lazily-generated (cached) delegate for each type `TT`, so that if `TItem` implements `IEquatable<TT>.Equals` it would create a delegate to a static method that would call that, and otherwise it would create a delegate to a static method that used some other comparison or, for some type combinations `TT` and `T`, simply returned -1.

Comment: The important point here is that type system doesn't know how `IndexOf` treats the `Square`. The type system has to consider the method might be adding a `Square` to an internal `Circle` array, which would throw at runtime. The type system is supposed to prevent that. .NET arrays do allow these kinds of co-variant bugs to slip through the type system.

Answer (score 6):

Since `IReadOnlyList<T>` is covariant, you can cast it to any supertype of `T` and all methods should still work according to the contract. The most super supertype of `T` is `Object`, so if `IndexOf` were part of the interface, it should have accepted `Object`.

As Jon Skeet states, in a list of `Circle` objects, you can then ask: what is the index of a particular `Square` in this list? The only correct response would be "it is not here," and `IndexOf` should return -1 and not throw an exception.

So, I don't agree with Jon Skeet. Given the limitations of covariant generic parameters, and similar to [`ArrayList.indexOf` in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29), the BCL team should have included a method `IndexOf` with the following signature:

```
int IndexOf(object item);
```

Exactly the same argument applies to `Contains` in `IReadOnlyCollection`: when you pass in an object of an incompatible type, the collection obviously doesn't contain it and the method should just return `false`.

The only downside would be boxing of value types, but actual implementation can still hide the `IReadOnlyList.IndexOf` method and provide their own generic overload, making this argument moot.

So, you are correct in expecting `IndexOf` to return -1 when passed an incompatible object, if it were on the interface.

---

I implemented this principle in my `M42.Collections` library to show how this would work in practice. You can download it here:

> [**M42 Collections**](https://bitbucket.org/Virtlink/m42-collections/) - Portable .NET library for working with collections properly.

Comment: The parameter to `Equals` is funny, in that from a performance standpoint it could benefit from being generic, but from a semantic standpoint it's both covariant and contravariant (meaning not really generic).  It's perfectly reasonable to regard `List<Cat>` as a "thing that can be asked if it contains a given `SiameseCat`", or "thing...given `Animal`", or even "thing...given `Dog`".  The answer in the latter case would be "no", but that doesn't mean the question couldn't be asked.

Answer (score 1):

Note that it would be correct, in theory (not sure if that is implemented in .NET yet), to define `IndexOf` for all subtypes of `T`:

```
class ReadOnlyList<+T> = { ...
  Int IndexOf<U>(U elem) where T : U { ... }
}
```

It is interesting to see why `IndexOf(T elem)` would not obviously be covariant, while this one is: if you have `T2 : T1`, a method `IndexOf(T1 elem)` may not be compatible with the signature `IndexOf(T2 elem)`. On the contrary, if you have `IndexOf<U>(U elem) where T1 : U`, you know that `T2 : T1` and `T1 : U`, so you also have `T2 : U` for all such `U`: this type is a subtyping of `IndexOf<U>(U elem) with T2 : U`.

This remark is made, for example, in the 2006 article [Variance and Generalized Constraints for C# Generics](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64042)
 by Emir, Kennedy, Russo and Yu: they present a type system that would accept this definition.

Comment: I don't think the parameter of the generic `IndexOf` should be constrained.  It's perfectly reasonable to ask a `List<Cat>` whether it contains a given instance of `Animal`, or `SiameseCat`, or even `Dog`.

Comment: All those examples would be allowed with the signature I gave, using subtyping either on the argument or on the list itself. `SiameseCat` is a supertype of `Cat` so you can directly use `List<Cat>.indexOf<SiameseCat>`. A `List<Cat>` is also a `List<Animal>` so you can use `List<Animal>.indexOf<Animal>` or `List<Animal>.indexOf<Dog>`. The comparison will be performed at the most precise common superclass of the two objects.

Comment: My point is that there's nothing wrong with `ReadableList<Cat>.IndexOf<Animal>`.  If method `foo` in a class with unrelated generic type parameters `T` and `U` receives a `ReadableList<T> list` and an `U item`, and wants to know if `list` contains `item`, that query would be meaningful if `T` is a subclass or superclass of `U`, and would have well-defined semantics even when the types are unrelated.  The query should not require `foo` to determine any class relationship between `T` and `U`, especially since the actual types of the list and item may allow the IndexOf method...

Comment: ...to early exit even if the types `T` and `U` are such that some instances of `U` would fit in some instances of `ReadableList<T>`.  Depending upon the types of `T` and `U`, it may be possible to skip the test either because all `U` will fit in all `ReadableList<T>`, or because no `U` will fit in any `ReadableList<T>`, but in general the decision would be best made within the `IndexOf` method.

Comment: If `T` and `U` are unrelated, I don't think it makes much sense to test whether a `U` is in a `List<T>` -- I would rather have the compiler reject it than return `false` -- because I think comparison should only compare two values of the same type. It seems that you have a different opinion on the typing of comparison, but I'm not quite sure what the benefit would be. If we know statically that it will always return `false`, then we may as well not test it -- and it is probably a mistake of the programmer.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to compare things of two *fully-specified class* types, since they cannot possibly be equal, but generic types are another story.  In the generic family `Foo<T,U>` with no constraints on `T` and `U`, there will be some classes (e.g. `Foo<String, Stream>` where instances of `T` cannot possibly be instances of `U`, some (e.g. `Foo<IComparable<Int32>, Int32>`) where some `T` will be instances of `U`, and some (e.g. `Foo<Int32, Int32>` where all `T` will be instances of `U`).  If the only thing the class cares about is whether a particular instance of `T` matches...

Comment: ...any of the `U` in a collection, examining the relative types may allow for useful performance optimizations, but the *semantics* should be equivalent to comparing with every `U` in any case.  Casting to object prior to comparison would work, but would result in unnecessary and potentially-expensive boxing in the case where `T` and `U` happen to be the same value type.